# Angular 10 testing in spec file, seemingly random cases fail

Tags: angular

I am creating tests for an Angular app in the `spec.ts` of a component. The tests each simply are testing for particular values and equalities. The `beforeEach` looks like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ HomeComponent, SideNavComponent ],
  imports: [ RouterModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(), MatSelectModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [ SharedService, BoxMedicalClientService, HttpClient, HttpHandler, UserAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService,
    { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: AuthenticationServiceStub } ]
})
  .compileComponents().then( result => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
}));
```

[image: Example error messages]

Anywhere from 0 to 3 errors seem to occur each time we rerun the exact same test, and every time we will get the error `Uncaught [object Object] thrown`. We're not sure what could be causing what seems to be such an inconsistent and random error.

Comment: I have faced these errors several times, in most of the cases this error occurs when we don't handle asynchronous request in spec file properly. Make sure your response object in stubs is correct.

Comment: Make sure everywhere where you create a promise from your test and it fails, you catch it.